# Ninject Binding Conditionally When Injecting To A Generic Interface

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

I have the following code structure which I want to compose with Ninject:

```cs
ICommandHandler<FindAssetById, Asset> handler =
    new SecurityCommandHandlerDecorator<FindAssetById, Asset>(
        new SecurityValidatorComposite<FindAssetById>(
            // This list contains both non-generic as generic implementations
            new ISecurityValidator<FindAssetById>[]
            {
                // Contains type constraint 'where T : IRequireAccessToAsset'
                new RequireAccessToAssetSecurityValidator<FindAssetById>(...)
            }),
        new FindAssetByIdHandler(...));
```

I have this setup in my Ninject:

```
//Bind Composite To Handler
_kernel.Bind(typeof(ISecurityValidator<>))
 .To(typeof(SecurityValidatorComposite<>))
 .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(SecurityCommandHandlerDecorator<,>));

//Bind Interface To Concrete
_kernel.Bind(typeof(ISecurityValidator<>))
  .To(typeof(RequireAccessToAssetSecurityValidator<>))
  .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(SecurityValidatorComposite<>));

_kernel.Bind(typeof(ISecurityValidator<>))
  .To(typeof(RequireAccessToSecureAssetSecurityValidator<>))
  .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(SecurityValidatorComposite<>));
```

I want to be able to conditionally bind the concrete validators if the calling parent implements the corresponding interface.

For instance a class like this:

```cs
public class FindAssetById: IRequireAccessToAsset{

}
```

Should get the `RequireAccessToAssetSecurityValidator` but not the `RequireAccessToSecureAssetSecurityValidator`. With Ninject the current way it is setup it obviously gets both. But with Ninject you can't call `WhenInjectedInto` and a conditional `When` statement. With how difficult this has been I'm assuming at this point I am way off base and how to implement and any suggestions to fix this would be very helpful.

In Simple Injector the equivalent would be something like this:

```cs
container.Register(
    typeof(ISecurityValidator<>),
    typeof(SecurityValidatorComposite<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.Collection.Register(typeof(ISecurityValidator<>), assemblies);

container.Collection.Append(typeof(ISecurityValidator<>), 
    typeof(RequireAccessToAssetSecurityValidator<>));
```

And somehow it knows to apply the right one or the example provided is incomplete. I'd like to replicate something like this with Ninject as I think the solution from here is fairly clean and where I got most of my code from https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices/issues/4. This is my first foray into really trying to understand DI and how I can apply the decorator pattern with it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Stevenfowler16, I'm sorry I can't help you with how to do configure this with Ninject. I did, however, update your question to show an object structure that I think you wish to create (please review and update). This hopefully makes it easier for others to help you. Do note, however, that Simple Injector was especially created with these types of designs in mind (batch registration of generic types, generic decorators, and generic type constraints). This might be much harder to achieve using Ninject, but I let others be the judge of that.

Comment: Looks great thank you. I'm fairly close I think. I need to .When(GenericConstraintCondition && OnlyWhenBeingInjectedIntoTheCompositeType). I have the GenericConstraintCondition and now I'm figuring out the OnlyWhenBeingInjectedIntoTheCompositeType conditional

Comment: To comment on "somehow it knows to apply the right one": Yes, Simple injector "knows", which happens because it [differentiates between collection registrations and one-to-one mappings](https://simpleinjector.org/separate-collections), which is very different to the API of most DI Containers. This means that if you inject/resolve `ISecurityValidator<T>` you *always* get the `SecurityValidatorComposite<T>`, but when you inject/resolve an `IList<ISecurityValidator<T>>` (or any other list) you get only things that are registered through `container.Collection.[Register|Append]`.